# Toggle between 2 check boxes using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I'm having difficulty in using jquery to toggle between 2 checkboxes..Currently this is what i have.

```
<div id="chkBoxList"  onclick="CheckBoxToggle()">
  <font size="2">
 <input type="checkbox"  class="all" name="empType" id="empType1" value="BWR is a Full Time employee. " checked="checked"  disabled="disabled"/>
  Full Time
 <input type="checkbox" class="all"  name="empType"  id="empType2" value="BWR is a Part Time employee. " /> Part Time
 </font>
 </div>
```

jquery follows thus.

```
function CheckBoxToggle() {


$('#chkBoxList').click(function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
    $checkbox[1].checked;
    $checkbox.trigger('change');
});



}
```

But this either toggles both to checked or unchecked. Since, initial value for one is checked and disabled, when clicked on second i want other to be checked and disabled while the first will be unchecked and disabled. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for using check boxes instead of radio buttons? If you can only pick one option, radio options are what you need.

Comment: `$checkbox.each(function() { $(this).prop.....etc });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .each() to loop through $checkbox.

```
$(function(){
    $('#chkBoxList').click(function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');

    $checkbox.each(function(){
       $(this).prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
        });


    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPstq/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try radio buttons too which is also easier. But, i'm in a process of learning jquery so want to lean more towards it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<body>  
<form name=f1 id=f1>
<input type=checkbox name=chk1 id=chk1 onclick=javascript:document.f1.chk2.checked=!document.f1.chk1.checked;> Check 1<BR>
<input type=checkbox name=chk2 id=chk2 onclick=javascript:document.f1.chk1.checked=!document.f1.chk2.checked;> Check 2<BR>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.all').click(function(e){

    $('input.all').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled',false) ;
    $(this).prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', true) ;


}) ;
```